# Friend request and friends list with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am building an ionic2 application with AWS Cognito and DynamoDB, I want to create a friends section in it, Is it a good method to create a a `friends` attribute inside Cognito User Pool Id, If yes will i be able to access my friends data or do i need to create a `profiles` table in DynamoDB and access its data and create friends list in return

Answer (score 0):

Anything you store in cognito is accessible only to the User herself. So lets say you want to create a feature where Bobby is able to see a list of Amy's friends. This will not be possible if you store Amy's friends in her cognito dataset. With Bobby's credentials you won't be able to access Amy's cognito. 
So, if the data needs to be accessed by others, you'd need to store it in something like DynamoDB.

Comment: Cognito team member here. It sounds like they are using Cognito User Pools, which would be different than Cognito Sync as it has it's own data store, but this answer is still correct. User attributes aren't world readable, so you would need an external data store (your suggestion of Dynamo is totally fine).

Comment: @JeffBailey is it not possible to use `identityId` from federated identities

Comment: I know this is old but do you have any links to tutorials on how to do this? I'm working on an application right now and stuck on this part of building a friends list and request system using cognito and dynamodb.